# What will the sql statement "DELETE FROM sales" do?

Tags: delete, rollback

```
DELETE FROM sales;
```

And if there are no other uncommitted transactions on the `sales` table. Which statement is true about the `DELETE` statement?

1. It removes all the rows in the table and deleted rows **cannot be rolled back**
2. It removes all the rows as well as the structure of the table
3. It would not remove the rows if the table has a primary key
4. It removes all the rows in the table and deleted rows **can be rolled back**

of course, right answer lays between 1 and 4. I don't know whether the deleted data can be rolled back or not.

If any one knows, please help me. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The delete statement without the where clause delete all rows in the table without change of table structure. If the delete statement is within a transaction, then it can be rollback before the transaction is committed.

If the delete transaction has been committed, the deleted transaction can't be rollback. Unless use of third party tool or restore the log backup to previous point if available.

Comment: You mean that if no error happened , the deleted data cannot be rolled back ,right?

Comment: @facebook-100005613813158: no. If it has been *committed* it can't be rolled back.

Comment: @facebook-100005613813158 You can rollback transaction with/without error as long as the transaction has not been committed. The key word is 'committed'. Please refer this msdn article for more information on transaction. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174377.aspx